# Gateway Error on Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, spree

I have just integrated the pagar.me gateway into the spree, I have already set the API and Encryption keys, however, whenever I try to make the payment, it does not complete and the following error occurs:

Gateway Error
  ---! Ruby / object: ActiveMerchant :: Billing :: Response
Params
  Errors:
  - parameter_name: customer [name]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: name is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [email]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: email is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [document_number]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: document number is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [address] [zipcode]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: Zip code is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [address] [neighborhood]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: neighborhood is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [address] [street]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: street is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [address] [street_number]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: street number is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [phone] [number]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: phone number is missing
  - parameter_name: customer [phone] [ddd]
    Type: invalid_parameter
    Message: DDD is missing
  Url: "/ transactions"
  Method: post
Message: name is missing
Success: false
Test: true
Authorization:
Fraud_review:
Error_code: processing_error
Emv_authorization:
Avs_result:
  Code
  Message:
  Street_match:
  Postal_match:
Cvv_result:
  Code
  Message: